# What is the best way to charge for software and infrastructure support?

Tags: frameworks, billing

We have an internal software development team in my company that are building a set of software frameworks and some infrastructure (database hosting) to be used by other teams.  Since they are not delivering software directly to any external client, they are trying to figure out how to chargeback to recoup their costs / budget  They are trying to determine the correct payment model for other teams to use their services.  So essentially we would be paying for the following resources:

- Using the software frameworks
- Using the infrastructure (servers - disk, memory, etc)
- The support people in this group to maintain the infrastructure
- The developers that are building the frameworks.

This seems like a generic problem that must exist with other software shops so I wanted to see if there was some standard or a suggestion here?

Comment: I don't think this is the appropriate place to post such a question

Comment: @user1291492 - what would be your suggestion for which SE site this question would fit better?  I thought about it and ultimately this seemed like the best audience to answer this question

Comment: I recommend this be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are considering this kind of relationship within a shop is probably very symptomatic of our times. If you think the framework team is useful, then measure its usefulness, in a somewhat fine-grained way, and just give the team the budget to keep being useful!

For example, have other teams assess their use of specific features in the framework and their wishlists, and check that the framework team only works on parts of the code relevant to those.

Paying for services could have some problematic drawbacks, as with any such arbitrary metric. For example, it gives other teams an incentive not to use their services: it encourages homegrown indrastructure, custom code(so you get a more potent NIH syndrome).

Answer (score 1):

What about estimating the cost of each tasks?

Every company I worked at, used a classical **man/day** system.

When a task has to be done, the human resource cost is assessed in man/days, that is, how many days would it takes if only one worker was on this task?

With that in mind, with an estimate of the time spent to do a task (often done by the more experienced people) and since you (should) know how much a worker costs, it's easy to find how much doing the task would cost (time estimated x cost of worker). That way, some very basic and redundant tasks, like reading a new database, a new server, creating new accounts... can easily have a basic man day cost.

And to optimize the budget the company can easily look at the tasks that are the most redundant and expensive to automatize them and reduce the overall costs of a team. Of course, the automation of a task is a project in itself and need to be estimated. And depending on the productivity gain of project some priorization has to be done.

I think that the main driver of this cost assessment is having projects/tasks and time tracking system. That way it's easy to produce statistics on what takes times.